# Is there any script or technique to "explode" Korean syllabic blocks into their individual characters

Tags: cjk

I have a CSV file and one column contains several words of Korean (they are names of products). I'm trying to make this text searchable with a tool that lets me only enter one Korean letter at a time.

So in my data I have 쌀, but when searching I can only type "ㅆㅏㄹ". So, I'd like to extract from my source data to have all of the "ungrouped" letters, in the proper order (top row left to right, then bottom row left to right) and store the separated characters in a separate CSV column, and use that column for my search parameter. But I have no idea how to "undo' the grouping of the letters into a long string of single letters in the correct order.

I feel like I must not be the first person who ever tried to do this... but I can't seem to find any examples. I don't speak Korean and can't find any English site which explains how to do what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/JDongian/python-jamo - it is written to do exactly the sort of thing you are talking about.